# How to move "1 day at a time" with XCOM?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

A follow up on a comment i saw on on stack exchange regarding `xcom`

> "You should NOT start building satellites until there are only 21 days
>   remaining for that month (i.e. build on the 8th for Feb, 10th for
>   March etc). This means you maximize the chances you will have more
>   engineers before building the satellite (which you will launch on the
>   final day of the month) and thus have the cheapest satellite possible."

How can I move 1 day at a time?

Comment: You can't. Time passes on a per-minute basis.

Comment: @Nolonar Ok. Is it possible to stop time to take action? Is it possible for example to start satelite research 21 days before end of month.

Comment: @Jam Time only passes as long as you're in *Mission Control*. When you click on *Scan activity*, time will pass a lot faster. Clicking *Scan activity* again, will make the time flow slowly again.